# Problems with starting C++ CORBA Server on Ubuntu, CORBA::SystemException

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, corba

I'm trying to run an example of CORBA in C++ on Ubuntu 12.04:
http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/CORBA.html

and I still have an error when I'm trying to run:

```
    $ ./Server
'IOR:010000001600000049444c3a446174612f53657276696365413a312e3000000001000000000000006800000001010200100000003139322e3136382e3135392e31323900b1aa00000e000000fe4ba4015100001a19000000000000000200000000000000080000000100000000545441010000001c00000001000000010001000100000001000105090101000100000009010100'
Caught CORBA::SystemException.
```

before starting Server I generated a log file:

```
omniNames -start 2812 -logdir ~/Desktop -errlog ~/Desktop/omniNamesError.txt
```

which gave me a file ~/Desktop/omniNamesError.txt as below:

```
Thu Jan 24 22:54:34 2013:

Starting omniNames for the first time.
Wrote initial log file.
Read log file successfully.
Root context is IOR:010000002b00000049444c3a6f6d672e6f72672f436f734e616d696e672f4e616d696e67436f6e746578744578743a312e30000001000000000000007400000001010200100000003139322e3136382e3135392e31333000fd0a00000b0000004e616d6553657276696365000300000000000000080000000100000000545441010000001c0000000100000001000100010000000100010509010100010000000901010003545441080000009aad015101004982
Checkpointing Phase 1: Prepare.
Checkpointing Phase 2: Commit.
Checkpointing completed.
```

Next I added at the file:

```
/etc/omniORB.cfg
```

line from the generated file:

```
InitRef = NameService=IOR:000100010000000100010509010100010000000901010003545\
441080000005ea5015101002002010000002b00000049444c3a6f6d672e6f72672f436f734e61\
6d696e672f4e616d696e67436f6e746578744578743a312e30000001000000000000007400000\
001010200100000003139322e3136382e3135392e31333000fd0a00000b0000004e616d655365\
7276696365000300000000000000080000000100000000545441010000001c000000010000000\
1000100010000000100010509010100010000000901010003545441080000009aad0151010049\
82
```

I also set environment variable:

```
$ export OMNIORB_CONFIG=/etc/omniORB.cfg
```

everything as it is written at tutorial, files compiled (after 2 modifications:
I added: *#include*  at CRequestServiceA.cpp
and I changed *$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) DataSK.cc* into *$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) DataSK.cc && mv DataSK.o Data.o* in MakeServer) but I still have an error as I told.

**Please help me with the problem, I was learning from many CORBA C++ tutorials and no effects**

Comment: Did you build omniORB from source or install the Ubuntu packages? If you built from source, what version did you build?

Comment: I installed it from Ubuntu packages. Installed version of omniORB I have is 4.1.6-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those backslashes in your config file might be causing the problem. To avoid problems with pasting a lengthy IOR (that will change) into your config file, try setting your `InitRef` as follows in your config file (assuming your are running the name service on the same machine as your test program).

```
InitRef = NameService=corbaname::localhost
```

Or you could try pasting the IOR as one line (don't break the line up or add backslashes).

Or you could run your server like this:

```
$ ./Server -ORBInitRef NameService=corbaname::localhost
```

Or

```
$ ./Server -ORBInitRef NameService=IOR:010000002b00000049444c3a6f6d672e6f72672f436f734e616d696e672f4e616d696e67436f6e746578744578743a312e30000001000000000000007400000001010200100000003139322e3136382e3135392e31333000fd0a00000b0000004e616d6553657276696365000300000000000000080000000100000000545441010000001c0000000100000001000100010000000100010509010100010000000901010003545441080000009aad015101004982
```

If you do use the IOR string, please realize it will almost certainly change every time you run the naming service, so make sure you are using the most current one.

Please see the [omniORB documentation](http://omniorb.sourceforge.net/omni41/omniORB/) for more information.

**Edit after seeing your comment:**

The tutorial might be old and out of date. Try changing this line:

```
CORBA::Object_var obj1=orb->resolve_initial_references("OmniNameService");
```

to this

```
CORBA::Object_var obj1=orb->resolve_initial_references("NameService");
```

You may also wish to work through the Echo example in the [omniORB documentation](http://omniorb.sourceforge.net/omni41/omniORB/omniORB002.html).

Comment: Thanks much for your answer, I tried all alternatives you told, but unfortunately I still have an error.
I can add that the exception is thrown in line:
_ CosNaming::NamingContext_var nc = CosNaming::NamingContext::_narrow(obj1.in()); _

Comment: Thanks much for your answer! I changed as you told:
_CORBA::Object_var obj1=orb->resolve_initial_references("OmniNameService");_
to:
_CORBA::Object_var obj1=orb->resolve_initial_references("NameService");_
in both **Server.cpp** and **CRequestServiceA.cpp** files and it works now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Great! Again, I don't know how old that tutorial is you are looking at, but it might be better to work through the Echo examples in the omniORB documentation. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

I think I solve this: I changed `OmniNameService` to `NameService`, and added in my omniORB.cfg file:

```
InitRef = NameService=IOR:00010....
```

(the IOR name came from omniNamesError.txt), then run the server like this:

```
./Server corbaloc:rir:/NameService
```